# ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-error, session-cookies

Please help me, I cannot access my website it always shows the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time
>
> Filename: Session/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 282
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /storage/ssd2/495/19547495/public_html/application/controllers/Auth.php
> Line: 8
> Function: __construct
>
> File: /storage/ssd2/495/19547495/public_html/index.php
> Line: 316
> Function: require_once
> But, if i run the code in localhost works fine...

this is the code from session.php

```
    `isset($params['cookie_name']) OR $params['cookie_name'] = config_item('sess_cookie_name');
    if (empty($params['cookie_name']))
    {
        $params['cookie_name'] = ini_get('session.name');
    }
    else
    {
        ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']);
    }

    isset($params['cookie_path']) OR $params['cookie_path'] = config_item('cookie_path');


    isset($params['cookie_domain']) OR $params['cookie_domain'] = config_item('cookie_domain');
    isset($params['cookie_secure']) OR $params['cookie_secure'] = (bool) config_item('cookie_secure');

    session_set_cookie_params(
        $params['cookie_lifetime'],
        $params['cookie_path'],
        $params['cookie_domain'],
        $params['cookie_secure'],
        TRUE // HttpOnly; Yes, this is intentional and not configurable for security reasons
    );`
```

this is the code from auth.php

```
`<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
 
 class Auth extends CI_Controller
 {
 public function __construct()
   {
 parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->load->model('Auth_model');`
   }`
```

this is the code from index.php

````
define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
 
 /*
  * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
  * -------------------------------------------------------------------
  *
 ```
 type here
 ```
 
 And away we go...
  */
 require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
````

`

I tried to host it on 000webhost but an error appears like this:
[https://amin69.000webhostapp.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: please can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: Why are you not setting these values where you are supposed to set them? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=cookie#session-preferences